# Submit contact form without refreshing the page using jquery,ajax in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net-ajax, email-validation

I have tried everything by searching it on Google but I couldn't get what I wanted. I am making this project in Visual Studio 2015. I want the mail code for sending an email and the jquery code for sending the page without refreshing it. If the email has been sent and there is no error in validation,then a label should define that- Thank You for Contacting With Us...

Here is my Code:

```
<form id="contactform1" runat="server">
    <div class="contactimage">
        <img src="../Project%20Pics/facilities_1.jpg" />
        &nbsp;
    </div>
    <h1 style="z-index: 1000; position: absolute; text-align: center; top: 110px; left: 650px; font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 45px">Contact Us</h1>
    <asp:TextBox ID="Name" runat="server" CssClass="textbox1" placeholder="Your Name" ToolTip="Type Your Name Here"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" Style="top: 210px; z-index: 1000; float: left; color: #FF0000; font-size: 20px; left: 1030px; position: absolute; height: 22px; width: 500px"
        ErrorMessage="* Name is Mandatory"
        ControlToValidate="Name"> 
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

     <asp:RegularExpressionValidator Display = "Dynamic" ControlToValidate="Name" ID="RegularExpressionValidator2"
          ValidationExpression = "^[\s\S]{3,20}$" Style="top: 210px; z-index: 1000; float: left; color: #FF0000; font-size: 20px; left: 1030px;
          position: absolute; height: 22px; width: 500px"
          runat="server" ErrorMessage="Length should be between 3 and 20 characters">

     </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

    <asp:TextBox ID="Email" runat="server" CssClass="textbox2" placeholder="Your Email" ToolTip="Type Your Email Here"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" Style="top: 260px; z-index: 1000; float: left; 
        color: #FF0000; font-size: 20px; left: 1030px; position: absolute; height: 22px; width: 500px"
        ErrorMessage="* Email is Mandatory"
        ControlToValidate="Email"> 
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

     <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" Style="top: 260px;
    left: 1030px; position: absolute; height: 22px; width: 500px; font-size:20px; color:#FF0000;" 
    ErrorMessage="* Please Enter a Valid Email ID" ControlToValidate="Email" 
    ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

    <asp:TextBox ID="MobileNumber" runat="server" CssClass="textbox3" placeholder="Your Mobile Number" MaxLength="50" ToolTip="Type Your Mobile Number Here"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" Style="top: 310px; z-index: 1000; float: left; 
        color: #FF0000; font-size: 20px; left: 1030px; position: absolute; height: 22px; width: 500px"
        ErrorMessage="* Mobile Number is Mandatory"
        ControlToValidate="MobileNumber"> 
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator3" runat="server"
        ControlToValidate="MobileNumber" ErrorMessage="Mobile Number should be of 10 digits"
        Style="top: 310px; z-index: 1000; float: left; color: #FF0000;
        font-size: 20px; left: 1030px; position: absolute; height: 22px; width: 500px"
        ValidationExpression="[0-9]{10}">
    </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

    <asp:TextBox ID="Subject" runat="server" CssClass="textbox4" placeholder="Subject" ToolTip="Subject" OnTextChanged="TextBox5_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" Style="top: 360px; z-index: 1000; float: left; 
        color: #FF0000; font-size: 20px; left: 1030px; position: absolute; height: 22px; width: 500px"
        ErrorMessage="* Subject is Mandatory"
        ControlToValidate="Subject"> 
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:TextBox ID="Message" runat="server" CssClass="textbox5" placeholder="Write Your Message Here" Rows="5" TextMode="MultiLine" ToolTip="Write Your Message"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" Style="top: 430px; z-index: 1000; float: left; 
        color: #FF0000; font-size: 20px; left: 1030px; position: absolute; height: 22px; width: 500px"
        ErrorMessage="* Message is Mandatory"
        ControlToValidate="Message"> 
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
     <div class="submitbutton1">
        <asp:Button ID="Submit" CssClass="SubmitButton" runat="server" Text="Submit" Height="43px" Width="127px" ToolTip="Submit" BackColor="#7CCFF9" ForeColor="#000099" OnClick="Submit_Click" />
    </div>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=" " CssClass="SuccessfulLabel"></asp:Label>
</form>  .SuccessfulLabel {
            position:absolute;
            z-index:1000;
            float:left;
            top: 577px;
            left:554px;
        width: 441px;
        height: 57px;
        font-family:'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size:25px;
    }
```

Comment: i don't see any js in your code

Comment: I had javascript code but since it was not working,i deleted it and now I want help from you.